# What is the value of $\log_i i$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

What is the value of $\log_i i$

How to start?

Is it mathematically correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to define $\log_ab=\frac{\log b}{\log a}$, then $\log_ii$ exists and has multiple values. Starting from $\exp(i(4n+1)\pi/2)=i$ you may find $\log_ii=\frac{4n+1}{4m+1}$ for $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't 1 be the natural answer?